# OpenVPN: Push IP address/routes to client in non-TLS mode

Tags: openvpn, authentication, autoconfiguration

I am trying to push IP address and routes from OpenVPN server to client.
I am using pre-shared static key as authentication mechanism.

Client is giving following error:

"Parameter --pull can only be specified in TLS-mode, i.e. where --tls-server or --tls-client is also specified"

Q1: Is it possible what am I trying to achieve and how ?

Q2: As technically not clear why two things are dependent on each other: (TLS-mode and pulling config) , why that is enforced ?